# About inverse functions of a real or complex function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis I" written by Mitsuo Sugiura.

p.193

> Theorem 4.1
>   Let $K$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. For two open sets $A, B$ in $K$, we assume $f$ is a bijective function from $A$ to $B$, and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. If $f$ is differetiable at $x \in A$ and $f^{'}(x) \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y = f(x)$ and $(f^{-1})^{'}(y) = f^{'}(x)^{-1}$.

And my question is the following:

(1)
I don't think the assumption that $f$ is continuous is necessary for the proof of the theorem.
Am I correct?

(2)
I wonder if $f$ is a continuous bijective function from $A$ to $B$, $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.
and I wonder if $f^{-1}$ is a continuous bijective function from $B$ to $A$, $f$ is also continuous.
Am I correct?

Please answer.

Comment: (1) Correct. But you need that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $y$.

Comment: Thnak you very much, amsmath

Comment: I shoul've left away the "but". It's the condition that you need at minimum.

Comment: For (2), read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain ;-)